# Is it possible to run a smart rollup node and a octez node on two different machine?

Tags: node, smart-rollup, rollup, octez

I'm trying to deploy an octez node and a smart rollup node on two different machines.

First, I ran an octez node in one machine. I added rollup machine's IP using `--rpc-addr` and `--allow-all-rpc` to allow all the RPC endpoints on that side.

Then, on the rollup machine I was able to configure operator and deploy the rollup. But, when I try to run the rollup node (which is communicating to the other machine running `octez-node`), it gives the following error (even with `--better-logs`):

```
P2p_addr.of_string
```

However, I'm able to run it successfully on the same machine. So, is it because the rollup node needs to communicate with L1 node with a latency beyond external network's capability? Or, it is possible but, I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you are trying to do is definitely possible. Could you provide the command you are doing for the smart rollup node?

You need to configure the endpoint:

```
  -E --endpoint <uri>: HTTP(S) endpoint of the node RPC interface; e.g. 'http://localhost:8732'
```

For example:

```
./octez-smart-rollup-node-PtNairob -E https://rpc.tzkt.io/ghostnet run operator ...
```